# Develop custom GATT profile on Linux

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

I need to create a program implementing custom GATT profile on Linux PC.
Question is: what options do I have for this?

As long as I can see, the only option is to develop a program on top of BlueZ stack. I guess it should have some sort of API to implement custom GATT profile. Is my guess right? Are there any API documents? Or at least what header files should I browse? And it would be great to have an example of something similar.

Ah, yes, I need two roles, both GATT server and client.

Any other alternatives? other BT stacks? Or may be higher level libraries?

Comment: In Bluez there is a btsensor example which may help you to understand implementation of gatt profiles